# How to fade out an Activity's UI, and fade in another Activity's UI?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

For the moment I have two `AppCompatActivity`:

1. The main one, which only displays a launcher UI (i.e. : there is only my app's logo, shown in large size) (`ConstraintLayout`)
2. The home one, which displays both a Drawer navigation menu (`DrawerLayout`) and the real app's UI (`ConstraintLayout`).

I want to fade out my launcher UI during 2 seconds. After this animation, I will start the second `Activity`, which must be faded in.

How should I do this?

I looked for some `fading-in` and `fading-out` in the in `ConstraintLayout` and `DrawerLayout` but I didn't find them. The idea was to adjust their value within the `onCreate` event handler of the main and other `Activity` (for the `ConstraintLayout` of the main, and also for the `DrawerLayout` and `ConstraintLayout` of the other).

Comment: You should take a look to android transitions. More info here: https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity#java

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi Impossible. I have tried, but this transition concerns the main activity of my application. However, transitions must be used between 2 activities (of the same application). The transition I have written isn't executed. You can see my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52237312/why-the-xml-specified-transition-isnt-executed-or-why-its-specified-duration . I think I'm going to implement Aksh's solution. What do you think of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To fade out current activity:**

Create a style in res/values:

```
<style name="PageTransition.Activity" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@android:anim/fade_in</item>
    <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@android:anim/fade_out</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@android:anim/fade_out</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@android:anim/fade_in</item>
</style>
```

Then in your activiy's style which is usually Apptheme for MainActivity:
add this line :

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/one</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/one</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

> ```
>         name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/PageTransition.Activity</item>
> ```

```
    </style>
```

**To start next activity's UI delayed:**
For your case, you'll need to use handler to delay transitions:

```
 private final int interval = 1000; // 1 Second
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

        ValueAnimator animator1 = ValueAnimator.ofInt(10, 0);

        animator1.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {


                float x = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue() / (float) 10;
                yourview.setAlpha(x);
            }
        });

        animator1.setDuration(500);
        animator1.start();
}
```

Call this oncreate:

```
handler.postAtTime(runnable, System.currentTimeMillis() + interval);
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000); //two seconds
```

Obviously, you wanna set your initial alphas to 0.
Hope this helped!

**EDIT:**

Define your own fadein-fadeout anims if your want to customize duration...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quad"
    android:fromAlpha="startalpha" android:toAlpha="endalpha"
    android:duration="{YourDuration in ms}"/>
```

If the previous way fails for some APIs, use this before starting your activity:

```
...
overridePendingTransition(int enterAnim, int exitAnim);
startActivity(intent);
....
```

Comment: "**To fade out current activity**" : I tried to do that but the animation isn't executed. To be sure, I would want to test this animation with a duration. How could I specify the latter in the XML file?

Comment: I added `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_out_home_activity, 0);` but my main activity still doesn't fade in :-/ Can I show you the entire code?

Comment: overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_out_home_activity, 0): 0 is not any alpha value. so ,  use this: overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in_other_activity, R.anim.fade_out_home_activity);  Create anims first obviously; fade_in should be the first parameter

Comment: For the moment, I just want to set the fade in effect on the main activity. That's why I gave `0` as second param's value, as indicated in the documentation: (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity): "*exitAnim : int A resource ID of the animation resource to use for the outgoing activity. Use 0 for no animation.*". In fact for the moment, I want to fadeIn my main activity, then fade it out, then fade in the new activity.

Comment: Are you able to animate transition now? (As you said 0 is for no anim, but it creates somewhat jittery effect..)

Comment: MainActivity cannot be faded in oncreate as far as I know. But you can fade it out before starting another activity by that overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in_other_activity, R.anim.fade_out_home_activity) I told you earlier. It'll fade out mainactivity and fade in the to the intent

Comment: if you want to fade in mainactivity, you can use handler tho

Comment: Ah I think I got your point..you're able to animate when starting another activity;however, mainactivity doesn't fades in oncreate..Am I right..if so, use handler

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179699/discussion-between-jarsofjam-scheduler-and-aksh).